Russian movie - man gets stuck forever in small village (70s? 80?)
That must be a hard one...
I remember having watched a movie which must be from Russia, eventually from the 70s or 80s.
A bald man with mustache is travelling and the car gets broken. He goes to next small village and try to get help. For the rest of the movie he gets involved into many situations and he is never able to leave the village.
By the end of the plot a small boy tells him he had a vision (or a dream): the bald man's grave, dated 2046 or something - meaning that the man would never escape the village.
Did anyone see it and knows the name?

It's "Город Зеро" [lit. Zero City], 1988 (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zerograd)
A plot is not exactly the same as you described:
- protagonist has mustashe, but he's not bald;
- it's his business-trip, not just the broken car;
- it's a small city, not a village.
But he really cannot leave the city, and it ends like you described.

Before I can thank you for my entire life :-) I'm trying to find some trailer in order to be 100% sure - but it must be this one

just google videos on "Город Зеро", there is full legal version on youtube www.youtube.com/watch?v=MUpLDZ47VA4
